# Can I make a variable in Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Well I'm learning about list comprehension.

This is my sample code.

```
m = ["m","male","M","Male"]
f = ["f","female","F","Female"]
gen = ["f","M","female","Male","x"]
arr = []
for i in gen:
    if i in f:
        arr.append(1)
    elif i in m:
        arr.append(0)
print(arr) #It shows [1,0,1,0]
```

As you know, this is super simplecode. So I thought it could be made using list comprehension.

So I tried below code, but it shows me syntax error

```
arr2 = [1 if i in f  else 0 if i in m  for i in gen] #It shows me syntax Error at "for"
```

So I tried this code, and it runned.

```
arr2 = [1 if i in f  else 0 if i in m else 2 for i in gen] #it shows me [1,0,1,0,2]
```

However in this case, it contains 2 in last index. I must not contains 2.

So In this case, Can I get the result [1,0,1,0] by using only the list comprehension?

Comment: If your item is in neither of the two lists, nothing should be appended to the output - so, you can't do that with a list comprehension.

Comment: @SuperStormer, i runned `arr2 = [1 if i in f  else 0 for i in gen if i in m  ]`, but result was [0,0]. i need [1,0,1,0] !!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille well, not without making an already overwrought list comprehension even more unreadable, and less efficient

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, there is a work around, use a list comprehension and use `_ = [a.append() .....]` to add to the list only on certain conditions. However, I wouldnt recommend it as it is a bad use of list comprehension. Agree with you that its best to use regular loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right, "you can't" was an exaggeration. There are indeed several ugly ways to do it...

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [1 if i in f else 0 for i in [j for j in gen if j in f+m]]
```

No one said you cannot do a nested comprehension :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a list comprehension, you can add a condition after the loop part that checks if the value in `gen` is in either of the other lists. That way the value won't be added to the final list if that condition is `False`.

```
arr2 = [1 if i in f else 0 if i in m else None  for i in gen  if i in m or i in f]
print(arr2)
```

This is a bit intricate for a one-liner, though. I doubt that I'd remember what this is doing if I looked at it again a month later. The loop solution is much easier to read and understand, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

With a nested list comprehension:

```
[x for x in [1 if i in f else 0 if i in m else None for i in gen] if x is not None]
```

Returns what you want:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the presence in `f` to generate 1 or 0 and exclude genders that are in neither lists:

```
m   = ["m","male","M","Male"]
f   = ["f","female","F","Female"]
gen = ["f","M","female","Male","x"]

arr = [ int(g in f) for g in gen if g in m+f ]

print(arr) # [1, 0, 1, 0]
```